# Do Pokemon have default move sets?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

I am trying to find out if Pokemon have a set of default moves. I am talking about Gen 1 Pokemon here (or fire red/leaf green).

Besides a default set, can anyone find any charts with recommended move sets for each pokemon?

I have been looking, but haven't had much luck.

**EDIT:** I am looking for move sets at level 50 or level 100. Like, when you face AI in the battle tower or something, how is it determined what moves their pokemon have?

I ask because I'm making a battle simulator for fun and I would like to have a set of recommended moves for each pokemon, so people can just choose "use default move sets" instead of having to go through and customize everything.

Comment: What do you mean by default set? They learn abilities when leveling up, not sure what could be a default set....

Comment: sorry I meant for like battle simulations, like at level 50 or 100, i'll edit the post

Comment: Aaah you mean other trainer's pokemon. I see now.

Comment: Wild pokemon just use the last 4 moves the pokemon would know via leveling (i.e., if a 'mon learns a move at 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, any level 5 'mon would know moves 2,3,4,5 (having forgotten 1 when 5 became available)

Comment: Do you really mean first gen? I don't think 1st gen had a battle tower.

Comment: I'm not specifically talking about a battle tower, I just wanted you guys to get the idea. I don't even care if its an official list. I just want a list of recommended move sets for each Pokemon. See the last paragraph of my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pokémon do not have "default movesets" in the context of "non-customized movesets". The moveset of any Pokémon you encounter in the games is based on the location you're in (for wild ones) or the trainer you're fighting (for trained ones). As a result, there really isn't any way around manually determining movesets for each Pokémon you want to have - just like the Pokémon developers have to do.

That said, if you're looking for "movesets that do well and don't require much thought to implement", you can try poking around [Smogon](http://www.smogon.com/)'s strategies; for example, one [Charizard](http://www.smogon.com/dex/xy/pokemon/charizard) set they have listed is Dragon Dance, Dragon Claw, Earthquake or Fire Punch, and Roost. They tend to explain why their sets work well and outline what else should be in the team to cover weaknesses.

Comment: YES! thank you. It looks like Smogon has suggested movesets for most of the Gen 1's